# MySql -- Determine periods of missing data with query

Tags: mysql

I have a database that's set up like this:

```
(Schema Name)
Historical
     -CID      int UQ AI NN 
     -ID       Int PK
     -Location Varchar(255)
     -Status   Varchar(255)
     -Time     datetime
```

So an entry might look like this

```
433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 13:05:54
```

My question is, if I'm expecting 5 minute interval data from each of my sites, how can I determine how long a site has been down?

Example, if MyLocation didn't send in the 5 minute interval data from 13:05:54 until 14:05:54 it would've missed 60 minutes worth of intervals, how could I find this downtime and report on it easily?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm assuming that your time column determines the order of the entries in your table and that you can't easily (and without heavy performance loss) self-join the table on auto_increment column since it can contain gaps.*

Either you create a table containing simply datetime values and do a

```
FROM datetime_table d
LEFT JOIN your_table y ON DATE_FORMAT(d.datetimevalue, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(y.`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
WHERE y.some_column IS NULL
```

(date_format() function is used here to get rid of the seconds part in the datetime values).

Or you use user defined variables.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
y.*,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevDT, `Time`) AS timedifference
@prevDT := `Time`
FROM your_table y ,
(SELECT @prevDT:=(SELECT MIN(`Time`) FROM your_table)) vars
ORDER BY `Time` 
) sq
WHERE timedifference > 5
```

**EDIT:** I thought you wanted to scan the whole table (or parts of it) for rows where the timedifference to the previous row is greater than 5 minutes. To check for a specific ID (and still having same assumptions as in the disclaimer) you'd have to do a different approach:

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT `Time` FROM your_table sy WHERE sy.ID < y.ID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1), `Time`) AS timedifference
FROM your_table y 
WHERE ID = whatever
```

**EDIT 2:**

When you say "if the ID is currently down" is there already an entry in your table or not? If not, you can simply check this via

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), (SELECT MAX(`Time`) FROM your_table WHERE ID = whatever));
```

Comment: Fancypants, (Hahaha, I liked saying that) 

Can you give me an example on how I would do this for a specific ID (for example ID 80). 

This is an awesome answer.

Comment: I don't understand. ID is your primary key, isn't it? So my previous answer shouldn't give you correct result. Please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: fancyPants, I think that the above would work.   That being said, I think that I phrased my question poorly.   Essentially I want to track the current / past periods of downtime per ID so I can run a report on it and see the last X periods of downtime and how long they were.   So for example ID 1 goes down for 25 minutes and I run a query now while it's still off, I want to see that 25 minutes and the last (5? 10, I can change the limit to suit the report) periods where it was offline.

Comment: Also, I'm using your SELECT
y.*,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevDT, `Time`) AS timedifference,
@prevDT := `Time`
FROM Historical y,
(SELECT @prevDT:=(SELECT MIN(`Time`) FROM Historical)) vars
Where ID  = 53
HAVING timedifference > 10
ORDER BY `ID`
Limit 5 code, that worked well for me.

Comment: So everything's fine and you don't need anything more?

Comment: Well, the only thing that's missing right now is if the ID is currently down, it doesn't seem to be catching that.

Comment: So for instance right now I have ID 99 that's been unresponsive (due to client issues) for 1472 minutes, yet I'm not seeing that with the query at all.

Comment: @Damien.Bell Edited my answer again. But I have to ask for clarification, what does it mean when you say "it's unresponsive"? How's your workflow?

Comment: The scope of the program is something like this.   Client machines run a script that will securely update my MySql table with their present status.   If they lose internet connectivity, there won't be any entry there, which is what I'm testing (or trying to) test for.

Comment: Then my last edit is working for you? On the other hand I still don't understand how you know an ID which isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT h1.ID, h1.location, h1.time, min(h2.time)
  FROM Historical h1 LEFT JOIN Historical h2
    ON (h1.ID = h2.ID AND h2.CID > h1.CID)
 WHERE now() > h1.time + INTERVAL 301 SECOND
 GROUP BY h1.ID, h1.location, h1.time
HAVING min(h2.time) IS NULL
    OR min(h2.time) > h1.time + INTERVAL 301 SECOND
```

Comment: Sadly this query never completes on my MySql server, it's been running for a little over 600 seconds now.

Comment: What indexes have you defined on the table?

Comment: @rsanchez Doesn't matter much, not only is it a performance nightmare, but also will yield not the desired result. Look at your join on h1.ID = h2.ID. ID is primary key!

Comment: @fancyPants ID is not the primary key of the table, it's the ID of the location.

Comment: @fancyPants reading the comments it's obvious that it is not. There are several Historical records for each ID, and the OP is interested in the time elapsed between those records.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you are going to have some sort of cron job running to check this table.  If that is the case you can simply check for the highest time value for each id/location and compare it against current time to flag any id's that have a most recent time that is older than the specified threshold.  You can do that like this:

```
SELECT id, location, MAX(time) as most_recent_time
FROM Historical
GROUP BY id
HAVING most_recent_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 minutes)
```